# Get characters causing re.search to return None

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have several methods in a class that check user input for compliance with a rule.
They all look like the examples below:

```
def check1(self, value):
    regex = re.compile(r'^(\w|/(?!/))+(-(\w|/(?!/))+)*$')
    return re.search(regex, value)
```

or

```
def check2(self, value):
    regex = re.compile("^(filter_|input_|output_|util_)\w+(-\w+)*$")
    return re.search(regex, value
```

When re.search returns None I would like to capture the reason why it failed so I can show the human a message that guides them in correcting the error.

It would be nice to display something more specific than:

> You can only use the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or an underscore, backslash
>   or hyphen

How can I best capture the offending characters in the value that has been checked?

So for example, I could show the user:

The character "@" is not allowed

or

You must start the data with one of the words ('filter_', 'input_', 'output_' or 'util_')

Comment: I don't think, in general, you can automatically produce a pretty explanation for a regex. For example, I challenge you to translate [this one](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) into a human readable message :-)

Comment: I don't need the machine to make a human readable string, I'd just like to get some indication of the 'failure' mode.

Comment: I just had a look at the regex you linked.  Good grief. The real worry is that I know there are people who can read that regex as easily as I can read the cartoons in New Yorker magazine

Comment: You could apply progressively more strict regexes to find the point at which a match fails, but this is going to be pretty messy and error-prone, especially if you have any repeating groups, e.g. `([a-z] [0-9])+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary (or in addition) to a regex matching allowed input, which you use now, to capture offending characters you would need regexes matching forbidden parts:

```
result = re.search(r'[^\w/-]', value)
if result:
    print "The character \""+result.group(0)+"\" is not allowed."
result = re.search(r'^-', value)
if result:
    print "A leading \"-\" is not allowed."
result = re.search(r'-$', value)
if result:
    print "A trailing \"-\" is not allowed."
result = re.search(r'//', value)
if result:
    print "Consecutive slashes are not allowed."
```

and

```
result = re.search(r'^(filter_|input_|output_|util_)', value)
if not result:  # here you didn't say you want the offending characters
    print "You must start the data with one of the words 'filter_', 'input_', 'output_' or 'util_'."
result = re.search(r'^(filter_|input_|output_|util_)(\W)', value)
if result:
    print "A \""+result.group(2)+"\" is not allowed immediately following '"+result.group(1)+"'."
result = re.search(r'[^\w-]', value)
if result:
    print "The character \""+result.group(0)+"\" is not allowed."
result = re.search(r'-$', value)
if result:
    print "A trailing \"-\" is not allowed."
```